# How to exclude List of Strings in java with Dozer?

Tags: java, dozer

I want to exclude a fields which looks like:

```
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
fieldNames.add("fieldA");
fieldNames.add("fieldB");
```

And i see on Dozer webpage that I can configure somehow like:

```
BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(AClass.class, BClass.class,
                TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(),
                mapNull(true)
        )
       .exclude("fieldA") //here i would like to add exclude but the list
    }
};
```

But i don't know how to add a list of String to the .exclude method....can anyone helps to me?

Thanks a lot!

***UPDATE***

```
ClassA{
    private String fieldA, fieldB,fieldC; //so i would like to map just the fieldC
}
ClassB{
    private String fieldA, fieldB,fieldC; //so i would like to map just the fieldC
}
```

For mapper configuration:

```
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
fieldNames.add("fieldA");
fieldNames.add("fieldB");
```

there will be fieldnames what i would like to exclude from the mappnig.
So when i mapping, i dont want to map the List variable...
somehow go with for...and exclude it...

```
 .exclude(list.foreach(listElement -> listElement.toString())) // or i dont know how can i do that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i made this sollution.

```
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
List<String> excludeList = new ArrayList<>();
excludeList.add("fieldA");
BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
            protected void configure() {
                TypeMappingBuilder typeMappingBuilder = mapping(ClassA.class, ClassB.class);
                excludeList.forEach(typeMappingBuilder::exclude);
        };
mapper.addMapping(builder);
```